# How to check coplanarity of N number of vectors?

Tags: vectors

We know that if 3 3D vectors are given, then we take scalar triple product (box product) of these vectors to check there coplanarity (by the condition: if box product is zero, then coplanar). But what if N (where N>3) number of vectors are given and asked to check there coplanarity, then how would one go about it? Ofcourse we can take box product of 1st to 3rd vector, then 4th to 6th, then 7th to 9th, etc individually ,then take box product of 1st, 4th and 9th vector, and so on so forth. But is there any other, less tedious method for this?

Comment: Are you trying to determine whether or not the entire set is coplanar?

Comment: @amd yes, you got my question